# Grails creates old columns from in mysql database event on clean schema

Tags: mysql, grails, database-schema

During development I added some fields to some domain classes. Then after re-factoring these fields were removed.

But they continue to appear in database schema, even if I drop and recreate it between "grails run-app" invocations.

Can anyone give an idea of what's going on? There are no references to these fields any more in the app.

I'm running Grails 2.4.3 in dev mode with mysql 5.6

As a matter of fact this happens from time to time, i.e. sometimes after recreating the schema old fields are not created.

Here's my datasource config:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = "com.dropbyke.mysql.dialect.MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect"
            dbCreate = "update" 
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dropbike?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = "123"
        }
    }
```

UPD:

MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect  is custom dialect:

```
public class MySQLUTF8InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    }

}
```

Comment: have you checked to make sure your application doesn't have any database migration scripts that are running? look in `grails-app/migrations`

Comment: There are no scripts in grails-app\migrations